# What games can I play with friends in the confined space of the seating on a long flight?

Tags: air-travel, tips-and-tricks, long-haul, entertainment

**Background**

Imagine 8 people, around 24-26, book a 14 hour flight somewhere for vacation. They are seated in 2 rows of 4 seats in the middle of the plane, so there is no strangers in between any of them. It is also in economy so there is not that much space in between each seat. These 8 people prefer not to use the in flight entertainment or carry laptops/tablets onto a plane. Instead, they like to chat and play games with each other.

**Question**

Based on the way they are seated, is there a game that allows all 8 people to play? If not, what about a game for each row to play ? There are 4 people in each row.

Thinking about standard card games like Crazy 8's or Uno wouldn't work because of passing of cards and the amount of time it takes for a game to finish. I am open to any answer as long as there is an explanation why you picked that game.

Edit:

Didn't know there is no such thing as a 5 person middle isle. I change the number to 4 in a row therefore changing the total travelers to 8.

I don't necessarily agree with the "opinion based" flag since I am more concerned about games I can play in the confined space of the seating arrangement, and not "which games are best to play on a plane".

Comment: What kind of a plane has 5 seat rows? Usually's there either 4 or 6+ seats in a single row, not 5.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. I will change the question accordingly

Comment: http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/American_Airlines/American_Airlines_Boeing_777-200_A.php

Comment: Would you be able to use dice?

Comment: I'm open to any answer as along as there is an explanation on why that game was picked.

Comment: You might want to add the requirement "doesn't drive the other passengers crazy" Most passengers on long hauls want to watch movies, work or sleep. A very active and chatty row or two can be fairly disruptive and the neighboring passengers may view this as being inconsiderate .

Comment: @Berwyn oops, my bad. I've thought OP is referring to 5-seat rows, not 5-seat *middle* rows.

Comment: I spy.... something white and fluffy

Comment: @JonathanReez The OP did say the "middle" of the plane. I took that to mean the center section and maybe you took it to mean half way between the front and the back?

Comment: @JonathanReez one layout of a Delta L-1011 did (have a 5 seat center section), but it's been phased out.

Comment: I take it that no one has done this at all

Comment: @JonathanReez: [Behold](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/airports-and-aircraft/Aircraft/mcdonnell-douglas-md-88.html).  The surviving members of the DC-9 family (currently the MD-8x, MD-90 and Boeing 717) have 2+3 or 3+2 seating in economy.  Delta and AA use them extensively for domestic US flying.

Comment: What age are the people ?

Comment: Lets say 24-26 years of age, also edited it

Comment: Sounds like BA might in fact be doing a 5 row middle section soon on the 787s :/

Comment: There are many threads on boardgamegeek.com about travel games. Two of the best solutions: magnetic or peg-based versions of common gamrs like Catan, or adapting dice-based games by putting the dice in a snap-lid bowl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a variety of games that can be played by passing pieces of paper around, which you could do quietly and discretely. A quick [search for "pencil and paper games"](https://www.google.com/search?q=pencil%20paper%20games&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) or ["paper passing games"](https://www.google.com/search?q=paper%20passing%20games&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) indicates some that work with more than two players (or pair up and have a few games going at once). Some are more strictly "games" with an element of strategy, while others are entertaining activities with no particular winner. Some examples:

- [Consequences](http://www.wikihow.com/Play-Consequences)
- Write your own [Mad Libs](http://www.madlibs.com/) and hand them to other passengers to fill out. Mainly done in pairs, but people could trade off filling in alternate words.
- [Paper Telephone](https://www.thegamegal.com/2011/06/18/paper-telephone/)
- [Telephone Pictionary](http://www.greatgroupgames.com/telephone-pictionary.htm)
- Three word story game (write a story where everyone contributes three words at a time)
- [Dots and Boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_and_Boxes) (an actual game)
- [Walrus](http://www.boredgourd.com/activity/575/walrus.html) (you draw the things destroying the other things)

Some other ideas are listed on [papg.com](http://www.papg.com/) and [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/31b8ks/what_are_some_games_you_can_play_with_just_a/).

Comment: The pencil and paper games flew over my head. I can do Scatterogies on the plane. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 6):

How about you play the game of meditation (here's a link from a quick google, if you insist on an [app](http://www.sikhnet.com/karmagame/meditation-mini-game)). Sit silently, breathe and focus on [breath](https://thebuddhistcentre.com/text/mindfulness-breathing). Raise your levels of consciousness and everybody wins.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/2926/8763), I would suggest a physical alternative, like who can do the most pushups or who can hold the plank position for the longest time.

Comment: A group of 8 people doing pushups and planking on a plane are likely to be significantly disruptive of those around them.

Comment: @ZachLipton They should take turns. Most people will struggle to do more than 30 pushups and that takes just half a minute or so.

Comment: A 14 hour flight is bad enough for personal hygeiene / body odour already without adding push-up competitions...

Comment: @user568458 [See here](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-37482798) and [here](http://www.bbc.com/news/health-28934415): "One hunter-gatherer community was found to not only have a higher diversity of bacteria, but only one in 1,500 suffered from an allergy - compared with one in three in the UK." and [here](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/mar/08/shower-once-a-week-polluting-environment).