# What am I going to do to occupy myself on a plane?

Tags: air-travel

Just wanted to ask you guys on what to do. I have another flight coming up which is 10 hours and 15 mins just wanted to ask out of curiosity on what you guys would do for that time period on a flight. I'm open for ideas ?

Comment: "primarily opinion based" is a huge understatement.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and our format is very ill-suited to requests for suggestions or lists— especially as you have given no indication as to your habits, tastes, or preferences, nor why obvious things like reading, sleeping, or electronic entertainment are insufficient. I strongly recommend taking the site [tour] and reviewing the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: My apologies ...

Comment: My favourite thing is to write personalised thank-you notes to whomever I was visiting. I also weave decorative paracord. And I always have my Koran with me for reading and inspiration.  When I fly as a supernumerary (my normal situation), I'll invariably use my DeLorme to arrange Pizza (or etc) deliveries at refueling stops along the way.

Comment: Reading, sleep & alcohol, in whichever order & quarantines you prefer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather broad, and everyone has their own preferences, but a few things you could do include:

- Sleep (naturally or with the assistance of medication, though if you're unfamiliar with the effects of a particular sleep medication on your body, an airplane is a rather bad place to try it for the first time)
- Read a book or magazines
- Watch TV or movies (preloaded on your own devices or the airline's entertainment system, if any)
- Listen to music, an audiobook, podcasts, language learning tapes, etc...
- Do a craft like knitting or coloring
- Write something, from a travel journal entry to a novel
- Sort through your pictures on a laptop or tablet, either from the current trip or from past trips.
- Do work, if your job is such that there are tasks you can do on a plane)
- Surf the internet (if there's in-flight wifi available)
- Go to the bathroom, stretch your legs a bit
- Talk to your seatmate, but, and this is key, avoid bothering someone who doesn't want to chat
- Have a snack or a drink. Drink water to stay hydrated. Booze dehydrates you and is bad for dealing with jetlag, but it's also an activity.
- [Play games](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70902/what-games-can-i-play-with-friends-in-the-confined-space-of-the-seating-on-a-lon) with your friends or family, if you're traveling with anyone, or play solo games if you're by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Watch a movie or four, read a book, play games on your phone, talk to your seat mates, stare out the window....

Comment: Aright thanks guys, yea I don't fly often especially not on long flights. So just wanted to see what would be best, and of course a special thanks to zack for answering another one of my questions. Much appreciated:)

Comment: @JoshSmith if you find one of the existing submissions has answered your question, feel free to accept that answer by clicking the tick outline next to it - it's the done thing!

Answer (score 0):

Sleep.  Consider what longer flights are like (10 hours is nothing). Make up stories about your fellow passengers. Get in and out of your seat to annoy your seat mates.

The options are endless.

Comment: Sing endlessly a song about how "the blades on the turbine go round and round".